# Foundation footer, 100% wide

Tags: zurb-foundation

This is probably ridiculously simple but I can't understand how to make a 100% wide footer in Foundation 5. I tried with the following:

```
.footer {
    width: 100% !important;
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

and in the template

```
<div class="row footer">
 This is the footer
</div>
```

but the footer remains centered and with a width not equal to 100% of the page.
Is there some inbuilt way to do this that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your markup ?

Comment: Sure thing. I've updated the original post.

Comment: I need also to see the footer container.

Comment: It's literally just inside of `<html lang="en"></html>` below the body. Not wrapped around anything else.

Comment: Remove the row class from your footer. `<div class="footer">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation-5 css has a max-width property set to `row` class and width of 100%

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 62.5rem; 
}
```

You don't need to override `.footer` class `width` with 100% as it takes that anyway from row.

Override max-width property.

```
.footer{
max-width:none;
}
```

`P.S !important declarations should not be used unless they are absolutely necessary`

Comment: Problem with that footer is if I add something like `padding: 20px;` then it stops spanning 100% of the width again :\

Comment: it works with padding also .i just checked it on my local-machine. ..something else must be the problem..

Comment: Yes I think there must be some other problem I need to figure out. Thanks!